# What tools are available to identify which country a specific IP address is located in?

Tags: ip-spoofing, geolocation

In trying to identify the country a user logs in from, or to block country ranges for whatever reason (for example regulatory requirements) what tools, whether online or offline, are available?

Comment: Looks to me like it's assigned to an ISP in Sarajevo, Bosnia.  Can you explain a bit more about how you need to "protect" yourself?  Are you experiencing some specific attack originating from that IP?

Comment: Can you reword your question...as it stands, it is difficult to tell exactly what you are wanting to do. If you just wish to geolocate IP addresses, Tate's advice is simple to follow. If you wish to block an IP address that is simple as well. Are you wanting to block entire ranges based on country?

Comment: @Rory: And if its just about geolocation, it should be on serverfault.com...

Comment: @Herr, is there a reason you think this question should be on ITSecurity? @Rory lets give him a chance to explain or elaborate before modclosing...

Comment: Because besides being an server releated issue, this is more a thing for IT Security since it has to do with abuse to a system. 
This is why it's here, and i think i'm gonna delete it anyway before causing any confusion.
And thank you for the chance to speak, this should definitely be like this.

Comment: @Rory nice edit :). I tried to find some way to make it specifically pertinent - regulation, that's the key (as usual...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.analysespider.com/ip2country/lookup.php

Pasting your IP address[ 46.36.191.14 ] in the above website gives:

> Country : Bosnia and Herzegovina
>
> ISP   :       Logosoft, information engineering and Internet providing

You can Internet pings on Windows platform using a procedure such as

http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/04/12/blocking-ping-response-in-windows-to-prevent-hackers-from-finding-you/

If you are using Linux then you can use iptables to configure access controls but I think IP address to country location mapping is based on the data provided by IANA(Internet Assigned number authority).

Answer (score 12):

Use whois:  http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/

Or/and you can try IP address geolocation services, like:

> http://www.ip2location.com/
>   http://www.digitalenvoy.com/
>   http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip_locate
>   http://www.ip2country.com/
>   http://www.hostip.info/
>   http://www.atelierweb.com/iploc/
>   http://www.ip2country.net/
>   http://www.quova.com/

Answer (score 5):

If you are on the go and have an android phone...I have created a Android based IP-Geolocation tool that uses the [Maxmind database](http://www.maxmind.com/) to geolocate IP addresses. You can find it in the android market (search Geo IP) or download it from my [website](http://www.ericonjava.com/?p=403).

Also you can use the chrome extension that I created [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fadodjoencnnlijogpfpkmonlffhfdjp)

Answer (score 4):

One of the problems with finding the location of an IP address is that they change frequently.
Currently the addresses between 46.36.160.0 and 46.36.191.255 are assigned to BA (Bosnia and Herzegovina)

We use the service at http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity to import the current list of IP addresses and the code from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server/67215/
which allows us to have the address look-up internally.

Answer (score 3):

**Firefox extensions:**

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ip-geolocation-search/

This IP geolocation search is made to help you quickly find the physical location of an IP address or domain name. It displays on a Google Map with additional whois information. The data comes from MaxMind and multiple whois databases.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/show-location/

Show the server location of the current page in the status bar.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flagfox/

Displays a country flag depicting the location of the current website's server and provides a multitude of tools such as site safety checks, whois, translation, similar sites, validation, URL shortening, and more...

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hostipinfo-geolocation-plugin/

Displays Geolocation information for a website using hostip.info data. Works with all versions of Firefox...

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/worldip-flag-and-datacenter-pi/

REAL location of web server,IP,Datacenter,Ping,Traceroute,RDNS,AS. Often shows different countries from similar add-ons,because it is based on data from core routers worldwide,and not on whois data.Real Google's data centers.Providers looking glasses

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/domain-details/

Displays Server Type, Headers, IP Address, Location Flag, and links to Whois Reports. Shows links to check server status and cache when page fails to load.

**Chrome extensions:**

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dbpojpfdiliekbbiplijcphappgcgjfn?hl=en

This extension shows a country or region flag indicating the location of the website you're visiting. And the following information will be shown in the popup:
• Country or region name
• Domain name and IP address
• Geo information
• Google PageRank
• Alexa Rank
• WOT (Web of Trust) information
• Copy domain name and IP address to clipboard

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mdpfciefafhdagbdcnklaepcgeobgaok?hl=en

If you click the icon in the a tab that opened a web page, it shows the IP address of current web site, locate the IP geolocation on the map.

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/elfegfojpcmepihiggejnaklafccgflm?hl=en

GEO-IP LOCATION

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jhejngphiacapbgllhagbpdkkdieeaej?hl=en

Porting of FlagFox to Chrome. Displays a country flag indicating the location of the websites you're visiting

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lhgkegeccnckoiliokondpaaalbhafoa?hl=en

See the geolocation, DNS, whois, routing, hosting, domain neighbors and ASN information of every IP address.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the IP,you can submit it in http://www.whoisxy.com/ and get the country details registered with the particular IP.